# How to change the levels of a logic signal

Tags: voltage, level-translation, high-impedance

I'm looking for a component that can translate voltage levels from 3.3 to 5.0 V (LVTTL to TTL). This component will be placed in order to spy on a signal, it must therefore have a high input impedance so as not to disturb the signal.

Does anyone know of a component or circuit capable of achieving this, knowing that the bandwidth can vary from a few kHz to 20 or 25 MHz?

I am of course looking for the most energy efficient solution possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looked at the TI [Voltage translators & level shifters](https://www.ti.com/logic-voltage-translation/voltage-translators-level-shifters/overview.html) selection, and the [TXU0101](https://www.ti.com/product/TXU0101) could meet the requirements, and is a *Single channel fixed-direction level shifter*. The maximum data rate is listed as 200 Mbps.

The TXU0101 is only for a single bit, but the selection table shows other devices with more bits.

The [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txu0101.pdf) has tables which show the device characteristics with different combinations of V<sub>CCA</sub> (input) and V<sub>CCB</sub> (output) which will support translating from 3.3 V to 5 V. With V<sub>CCA</sub> at 3.3 V the *Electrical Characteristics* show input thresholds which are compatible with 3.3−V LVTTL.

The TXU0101 datasheet contains the following in the overview which could be useful when spying on a signal, in that should allow for the *spying* circuit to be powered down with disturbing the signal being monitored:

> This device is fully specified for partial-power-down applications using the I<sub>off</sub> current. The I<sub>off</sub> protection circuitry ensures that no excessive current is drawn from or sourced into an input or output while the device is powered down.

I<sub>off</sub> is specified as –2.5 to 2.5 µA

Comment: Thank you for your quick response I will try with this component.

Answer (score 3):

There exist families of 74xx style logic ICs that have exactly that behaviour. They are the 74HCT, 74ACT and 74LVC families (thanks to Hearth for reminding me of LVC). You start by selecting which logic function you wish to implement, such as NAND, AND, OR etc, and you acquire the appropriate IC:

- [74HCT00](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/74HCT00.pdf) or [74ACT00](https://www.onsemi.com/download/data-sheet/pdf/74act00-d.pdf): 4 × 2-input AND gates
- [74HCT1G00](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT1G00.pdf) or [74LVC1G00](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74LVC1G00.pdf): 1 × 2-input AND gate
- [74HCT08](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/74HCT08.pdf) or [74ACT08](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74act08.pdf) or : 4 × 2-input AND gates
- [74HCT1G08](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT1G08.pdf) or [74LVC1G08](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/74LVC1G08.pdf): 1 × 2-input AND gate
- [74HCT132](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hct132.pdf) or [74ACT132](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2032042.pdf): 4 × 2-input NAND gates with schmitt trigger inputs
- [74LVC1G132](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g132.pdf): 1 × 2-input NAND gate with schmitt trigger inputs
- [74LVC1G17](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/74LVC1G17.pdf) 1 × non-inverting buffer with schmitt trigger input

and so on.

The 74ACT family is faster than 74HCT, and may be more suitable for 25MHz signals, but I have had success using basic 74HCT gates at similar frequencies.

These devices have TTL compatible *inputs*, meaning that an input above +2.0V will be treated as logic high, and an input below 0.8V will be considered low, which also happens to be compatible with standard 3.3V logic levels. Having MOSFET gates as inputs, their input impedance is huge, and shouldn't influence the signal of interest much, if at all. Be aware, though, that at 25MHz *any* capacitive load, even the few picofarads of these gates, will slow signal slew rate slightly.

If frequency can drop to a few kilohertz, I would recommend using a schmitt trigger input device, which will have better immunity to false triggering due to slow slewing of the input signal.

The output will be a function of the device's power supply, so if you supply it with +5V, then it will output either 0V or +5V.

In terms of efficiency, the static supply current for these devices will be a few microamps (check the datasheet), but that will naturally increase with switching frequency. Don't forget to tie unused inputs to ground or +5V, to prevent parasitic oscillations, and increased power consumption.

Most of the above gates have multiple inputs, but you can tie an input permanently high (or low, if you are using an OR gate) to have the device ignore it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcMfiO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here's an implementation using a single 74HCT1G08:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLXpzi.png)</sup>

Don't be tempted to omit C1. At 25MHz you absolutely must have supply decoupling close to the IC's power pins. And I repeat, if you use a package with multiple gates, like the 74ACT08, never leave unused gate inputs unconnected.

Comment: The 74LVC series would also work, and has a wider selection of 1G parts, if that's important.

Comment: @Hearth Thank you, I overlooked that, I've updated my answer.

Comment: I find it handy to keep a supply of 74LVC1G17s (non-inverting Schmitt buffer) and 74LVC1G14s (Schmitt inverter) around--they come in handy surprisingly often. They also have well-matched propagation delays if you get them from the same manufacturer, so if you need to split a digital signal over a few dozen MHz into true and complement signals without introducing a phase offset, they're the perfect solution. That bit's not relevant to what's being discussed here, but I find it useful.

Comment: @Hearth I should get some LVCs, I don't keep any yet, but I have plenty HCTs for this very reason. Really, thanks for reminding me of the LVC variants, easy to forget. Personally, one of my favourite ICs is the 74HCT132 which I always keep handy; they are so useful for a quick oscillator or level translator.

Comment: Is it worth mentioning the different families can behave differently in _partial power down_, i.e. when there is an input to the IC but the IC isn't powered? Looking at the LVC variant datasheets they all contain ``This device is fully specified for partial-power-down applications using Ioff. The Ioff circuitry disables the outputs, preventing damaging current backflow through the device when it is powered down``. Whereas the datasheets for the ACT and HCT variants mention ``DC Input Diode Current`` meaning inputs may try and power the device through the clamp diodes, and cause problems.

Comment: @ChesterGillon sure, it's worth mentioning. To be honest, it didn't even occur to me that OP might power off the probe, or try to probe a powered-down system. But you addressed that in your own answer, and that might pique OP's curiosity.